# How to break inheritance

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am using Grails. I'm trying to use values from one source as a method of searching another source.

```
def numbers=[];
//collection of Info maps
somemaps.each{
    numbers.add(it.id);
}
//THIS IS THE LINE THAT GENERATES THE ERROR
def info=Info.findAll("from Info as i where i.site in (:xsites)",['xsites':numbers]);
```

But I get this error

```
Subtype 'java.lang.Integer' of reloadable type myservices.Info is not reloadable:
```

How can I break the values of 'numbers' away from Info so they no longer have that type in the inheritance chain?

Comment: You have an object of one type (an Integer). It *cannot* be treated as another *nominative* type (eg. an Info); because that's just not what it is. It's no more valid to do that then treat a bottle of ketchup like a car. You could treat it structurally (aka in a duck typed fashion although that will be of little use use), perform logic based on the actual type (ie. with an if), convert it to another value (and type) and somehow makes sense, throw out all such objects, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, my first question would be, is there a relationship between Info & Site. If so, why don't you try the actual identifier. As in,

```
def info=Info.findAll("from Info as i where i.site.id in :xsites, ['xsites':numbers]");
```

Or worse comes to worse, use createCriteria

```
def info=Info.createCriteria().list{
    site{
        'in' ('id', numbers)
    }
 }
```